# Sony Xperia Z ear speaker is stop working during calls?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia, speaker

In my Sony Xperia Z the ear speaker stops working during calls. When I press the top of the phone where the ear speaker is placed, it starts working but after sometime it stops working again.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my phone?

Comment: Sounds like a faulty speaker.

Comment: Is there any way I can fix that?